# Laravel : Image is Broken

Tags: image, laravel, laravel-5.3

i want to add two logo in the welcome page.i have stored the images in the folder named image under the public folder.In the build in homepage of Laravel i want to show these two images. i tried these

```
<image img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\officeapp\public\image\MB.png" alt="Logo">        </image>

<img src="{{URL::asset('/image/MB.png')}}" alt="logo" height="200" width="200">
```

but image is not showing only 'Logo' word is showing...what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**public_path()** (Get the fully qualified path to the public directory.)

```
<img src="{{ public_path('/image/MB.png') }}" alt="logo" height="200" width="200">
```

Comment: THIS IS  NOT WORKING

Comment: `public_path()` returns the absolute path to the public directory not the web path.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<img href="{{ asset('/image/nashicon.ico') }}" />
```